# If On First record take filed else sum varible numberVar in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

So i am working on report in crystal report and i have some problem

i have filed name opening that come from database

i have numberVar in the formula so

```
if   on first record to sum numberVar =(opening +INqty - Outqty)

else numberVar +INqty - Outqty
```

and i want for every item

but what happen is when the information on the first item end it take the last sum of numberVar  and sum to it the second item

this is my formlua :

```
numberVar BALQTY;

IF OnFirstRecord  THEN 
    BALQTY := 0 ;

IF OnFirstRecord  THEN 

BALQTY :=  {stockCard;1.open1}+{stockCard;1.InQty}-{stockCard;1.outQty}
ELSE
    BALQTY := BALQTY + {stockCard;1.InQty} -{stockCard;1.outQty} ;
```

any help plz

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, looks like you need to run for every record separately and your variable is retaining the previous item value, this is because of **incorrect variable declaration**

You have declared the variable with `Global` scope instead create a variable with `Local` scope.

Change `numberVar BALQTY;` to `Local numberVar BALQTY;`

Comment: Not every record ,I want every item separately  . I group by every item so after finish first item take opening for the item

Comment: Have you changed the code? It should work good even for every item